# viewing rtf or pdf on a site built using mvc 4 Ipad capable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for a simple way to view NOT edit either rich text formated files or pdf files on a website that will display well on an ipad. Basically I have a directory of word and power point documents I need to display. I can easily convert them to rtf or pdf or save them up to a database as varchar(max), whatever works best for displaying on site. I can handle the processing of the documents but how do I display them on the site. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google document viewer fairly easily within your website.

`<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=urltoyourdoc&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>`

you can find more details here

https://docs.google.com/viewer